# using async task for submitting large number of values in Realtime Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it necessary to use async task  while submitting large number of values like "2000" values at a time to Realtime Firebase Database or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase APIs for mobile clients are all asynchronous when reading writing data so you don't need to do it in `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use async task while submitting large number of values like "2000"

**Yes**
   Firebase APIs Use full in full using manithread so if you have large data with images that time your cpu take more usage so your ui get freeze....so in order to avoid that you need to   use background thread...

**Exampls**

```
class Myuploadtask  extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


                upload_5Images();  //call here

            return null;
        }

    }

    private  void upload_5Images(){
        //do you upload functions
    }
```

> **Note:** I have face same problem like when upload huge datas my progressdialog getting struck when use use background thread it got
>   solved.So my suggestion if you hug datas to upload better to use
>   background thread...